# Help me understand SO better, really confused now

Tags: discussion, support, comments, comment-replies

Context: See the comment I received from OP.

[image]

My Question: Is this how SO behaves normally, at least sometimes? Does it have to be something with the gender?

I expect the answer to be a strong negative, but just for sake of confirmation, I'll ask

Note:

1. I'm not much regular (unfortunately) here but till time, never experienced something like this.
2. Maybe it is not a big deal for some people, but in my case, I find it humiliating.

Nothing personal, tough. [The question in discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598508/student-database-project#30598508).

Comment: I stopped at implication of gender bias.  There is bias and discrimination on SO - against bad questions.

Comment: A stupid comment from a 1-rep user that is a member since today and has no other posts. Come on, give us a break. You have been a member for 1 year and 5 months and have over 50 posts; you tell us if this is how SO behaves normally.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I believe you're true. Point here is, I'm not used to this kind of comment and it makes me really feel bad. Now, I know this is not a place to complain, neither i'm doing one, just asking, it this somehow common around here? I heard these kind of comments are there in Linux Source codes also (did not come across myself, though) but I really don't feel comfortable at one thrown at me.

Comment: @NatashaDutta not at ALL saying what was said was okay. But as was pointed out... a 1 rep user, with one question, who was created today... honestly, you can't think THAT represents the community

Comment: If I was to make a post every time someone was rude to me on the internet, I'd be banned for spamming. Shrug it off, you'll need thicker skin if you want to hang around on the internet.

Comment: I agree that the SO comment was in vey poor taste, (at least).  Unless the question was discussing contract agencies and freelancers, I would never use the words 'prostitute' or 'pimp' in an open comment.

Comment: ..well, except on meta:)

Comment: @Patrice I don't want to. I expect SO to be an open platform, for everybody. but then again, the answer I received starts with a "Yes"...

Comment: @NatashaDutta read the answer. it basically says "yes, people post what they want, we will remove it afterwards". That's the internet. You took ONE sample. That idiot doesn't know how to behave. That is not SO's fault, I'd say

Comment: @NatashaDutta That answer may start with a "Yes" but it's also being disagreed with. No, SO is not a place where you can be insulted at every turn. If someone _does_ call you something that is completely inappropriate in a professional environment (which is what SO is supposed to be) then flag it as rude or offensive. If it's a comment, enough flags will delete it. If it's not flagged enough, a moderator will step in and take a look.  If the post is a question or answer, I believe it goes straight to the mods. Either way, it will be dealt with.

Comment: @Patrice please don't get me wrong, I'm not pointing finger to anyone, least being SO community. I know there are real good, helpful people around. But I really cannot take any such comment, it'll somehow ruin my day. :-(

Comment: Oh - the Oz troll has turned up:)

Comment: @NatashaDutta - don't let SO posters/commentes spoil your life too.  It's too late for me:(

Comment: @NatashaDutta Oh I can understand. One small comment like this can ruin your day easily, no matter how it was posted. The only thing I can point again is that you're asking if this is normal on Stack, when the user is a new user, who posted nothing. If you have that kind of message from an established, trusted user, it would be different. As long as you're on the internet, you'll have to expect crappy messages like that :(. Not saying it's okay btw, just pointing out how it is

Comment: @Patrice Thanks to you too. Leaving for the day. Hope tomorrow will come back with a fresh mind and will leave all this behind. appreciate.

Comment: That "prostitute" comment was not OK. You are not wrong to be upset by it. I hope the rest of your day goes better.

Comment: @NatashaDutta I hope you can :). I hope you can get a good day anyway. Remember that not everyone is as stupid as that user and that people do value your contributions to this site

Comment: I think most of the negative votes were aimed at the keyword 'student'. That together with words such as 'subjects' or 'marks' make users here associate it very strongly to a homework question. 

As you probably notice, regulars here generally have a very strong emotion (and sometimes uncalled rage) against homework questions. So maybe you if you have named you database 'medicine' and use fields such as 'quantity' or 'patients', you would probably end up with a different result.

HTH.

Comment: @chmod711telkitty The OP was asking about the comments related to prostitution, not about why the question was downvoted.

Comment: @chmod711telkitty: That is simply incorrect; homework questions _per se_ are not disallowed. Bad questions are disallowed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That comment was way over the line, and would not be tolerated from anyone on the site. The fact that this came from someone with an account with a female name probably indicates that this isn't gender-related. Abusive users can come from all backgrounds.

If you see something like this in the future, flag the comment or the post involved and we'll act on it. We don't tolerate insults from anyone.

In addition, it appears this user was attempting to work around a question ban using multiple accounts, so I've cleaned that up and addressed this with the primary account.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the support. Today I'm feeling upset and will take a leave. Hopefully when I'll come back tomorrow I will be able to overcome and ignore this incident. I seriously wish to continue here, so may good knowledgeable, helpful people around.

Comment: @NatashaDutta - I'm sorry that you had to experience that. We try to catch and deal with hostile users as quickly as we can, but no system is perfect. A site of this size will always have some bad apples in it, but the community does a great job of pointing this out when it happens. No one here tolerates insults.

Comment: Without blaming @NatashaDutta for the asker's reply, which was indeed an inappropriate personal jab, I think it's important to note that the initial comment did not initiate a helpful or constructive discussion of the post. [Solicitations of off-site answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83934/), especially [for money](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121938/) are not welcome on SO. If a "question" is just a gussied-up work order, then simply close it, perhaps with a comment about posting guidelines. The reply was absolutely over the line, but the exchange never should have happened at all.

Comment: @JoshCaswell So, do you (and 5 more comrades) think I was _actually_ asking for money? Are we that much thick skinned? You make me sad, again. I thought that part of humor is understood.

Comment: Tell me something Josh, are you really seeing this kind of comment (mine) for the first time ? Well, now I don't have a link back, but I'm almost certain that i've seen people jokingly mentioning the same. I believe, nobody will _ever_ ask for monetary benefit for sharing knowledge, least being the extraordinary people around here. I believe I have not put enough effort to become one of them (yet). :'(

Comment: I believe this thread is dead, but if "is there anybody out there", can you confirm, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668302/please-help-to-sort-out-this-questionn#comment49398626_30668302) is acceptable or not?

Comment: @NatashaDutta joke or not, the comment wasn't going to lead to anything constructive. Sure I've seen people write this before; I'm pretty sure I've even written it myself. Based on that experience, I'm suggesting to you that if that's all you have to say, you'd do better to skip it.

Answer (score 7):

Such comments could certainly appear on the site, as checking every posted question, answer and comment if it's offensive before it can be posted is not scalable and essentially assumes that most comments are offensive, which is not the case.

Therefore if you see such comments, flag them for moderator attention, as they're simply out of line.

Answer (score -15):

Yes, this is how SO behaves normally; when such a content is posted, it's flagged for moderator attention who removes it, or is removed as a result of community flags.

This comment wasn't appropriate regardless of the gender of anyone involved and should be removed, but the question got deleted before it could be done. We allow anyone to post anything and moderate it *after*. If you find this unacceptable you'll have to find a website that only allows approved, censored posts to be made.

To expand on the last thing I said; I don't mean to sound unwelcoming or to suggest in any way that you should leave. I am merely pointing out that you should be prepared for such accidents, because even with perfect moderation, a malicious, insulting intent can get through and will sting. The fact that we curate this site to a really nice level is one thing. The *fact* that some people out there don't care about others is another. Pretending it's not true would be an insult to the all hard work the moderators are doing on SO.

Comment: *"We allow anyone to post anything"* - well that's not true, the OP could only comment because it was their own post, they wouldn't have the rep to comment elsewhere. *"If you find this unacceptable you'll have to find another place on the internet"* - could you couch this in less confrontational terms?

Comment: There are also things that you can post that would end up with your comment being blocked and not posted (certain black-listed terms, anti-spam mechanisms, etc.)

Comment: @Servy this is certainly a good point.

Comment: @jonrsharpe to post such an offensive comment you could edit the answer text; it's an abuse after all (you only mentioned *where*, not *what*). As for "less confrontational terms" I personally think people get offended way too easily on the internet. We have a minimal age policy of 13 and that should be enough to realize that the person on the other side of the wire is outright toxic. If you can't deal with that on your own, then I honestly can't see how you can be a part of any open internet community, where such things *can* happen.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz any edits (again, except on their own posts) would need to reviewed, as the user has <2k rep. Whether or not people get offended too easily, you don't have to try to prove it! The last paragraph helps, though; thank you.